# CSS Cursor Event Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

I'm trying to make the cursor change on a specific event.. I don't know how to explain it but as an example, I want to change the cursor to progress when it's currently a pointer cursor (hovering links, buttons, else...) and I don't wanna type everything that has a pointer cursor like:

```css
a, input[type='button'], button {
    cursor: progress;
}
```

All I want to do is replace the cursor when it's a pointer to a progress.
Is this even possible? Even if it requires JavaScript or anything! If it IS possible, then please help me, I'll accept an advice, too.

Thanks in advance~

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible or not. Certainly not with just CSS. Either way I think you should just do this as you described. Specify all elements in your CSS that you want to change the cursor for. There aren't that many elements that use the pointer cursor, it wouldn't be hard to change them all. It would certainly be easier than writing a javascript solution, if that's even possible.

Comment: @moss You're actually right, but I want to change all the cursors to other, the above was just an example, I'll stick with CSS right now, but I'm still interested to know if it's possible or not.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because these elements have their default cursor set to auto. I don't think there is any way to determine what cursor `auto` outputs using javascript.

Comment: @moss Oh... I understand now! Thanks sir, can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that this is possible. The browser(*I've only checked chrome*) sets the style value of `cursor` to "auto" or "default". So even if you check the style of an element using javascript you won't be able to tell which cursor it is using unless you already specified it in your css.

You can test this with this jquery snippet:

javscript:

```
console.log($('button').css('cursor'));
console.log($('input[type="submit"]').css('cursor'));
console.log($('a').css('cursor'));
```

html:

```
<button>TEST</button>
<input type="submit"/>
<a href="#">TEST</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
a:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="button"] {
  cursor: wait;
}
```